# geolocation in html5 and js - I refused but I would like to accept - How to reset?

Tags: javascript, windows, firefox, geolocation

By going to this page with Firefox : https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation
After clicking on "Try it" a dialog box opened at the top of Firefox and I refused. How to make it appear again or reset for allow?

Thank.

Comment: I refreshed the page in Safari and it asks me again

Comment: Do I want to reset by code?

Comment: It is solved I was in about:config and I ticked "geo.ip = true" I probably changed this parameter 1 year ago ..

Answer (score 1):

You blocked geo-location permission so allow geo-location once again follow below steps:

1. Go to the address bar
2. Click on lock icon [left side of address bar]
3. It will show one pop up
4. Go to permission
   5 .Remove blocked temporally[image]
5. Refresh page
6. You can access geo-location